# How to hide logged In Layout when Footer Menus is clicked from a signed in user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have different layouts for "LoggedIn User" and "Non-LoggedIn User" Something like below.

```
@if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
else if (User.IsInRole("Candidate"))
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoggedInLayout.cshtml";
}
else if (User.IsInRole("Referrer"))
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ReferrerLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Now when a user is logged in and visits any page I show a `Left Nav Bar Partial View with some 5-6 menu items`.

[image]

Also, just like any other web sites I too have put footer as `"AboutUs" "Terms and Condition"`.

**Issue:**

Now when a logged in User clicks on any of the footer option, even in that case, the left nav bar menu item gets displayed. The reason for it to be getting displayed is because the user is logged in. But I do not want to show any of the Left NavBar Menu Options if user clicks on Footer Menu Item. Suppose a Logged in User clicks on "About Us" from footer, I want it to behave the same way, as if a Non Logged In user has clicked.

Expected Behaviour: Entire Page should be rendered the same way as if a non logged in user has clicked. No Left Nav Bar Menu Item should be shown. Example Website: [I want a behaviour just like this web site](https://uptowork.com)

Current Behaviour:

[image]

Expected Behaviour:

[image]

**My About.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

This is About us page.
```

Comment: I would assume you would just have `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` in your About.cshtml file. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TiesonT.: Added the about us page

Comment: Since nothing is mentioned in About us explicitly, It goes off of ViewStart.cshtml

Comment: @TiesonT.: So, I knew the theory, that If nothing is mentioned then ViewStart will take over. And if we mention a layout then it will be overridden. Never had implemented it practically, so it did not strike to me. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying the layout in a view will override anything set in, say the `Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` file. So, this should be all you need:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

This is About us page.
```

---

#### Overrriding views for an entire View folder

If all your views for a specific controller use a certain view, you can also add a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file to the Views folder for that controller.

For example, if you had a `FooController`, with a `Views/Foo` folder for it's views, you could add a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file there to have all of those views use `_FooLayout.cshtml` (or whatever). Everything else would still use whatever your "global" `_ViewStart.cshtml` file dictates.

You can see a practical application of this if you add an area to your MVC project; the templated code will add a _ViewStart within that area which, because it's more local, will override the non-area _ViewStart.

Comment: Additional Pointers are always helpful. :) . Now this is something new I learned, that we can overwrite the entire _ViewStart.cshtml (if required).